# XML get nodes with sub nodes

Tags: php, xml

I have the following XML structure:

[image]

As you can see, I have many nodes with the name "Activity"
Now I would like to know, how can I get all "Activity" nodes with their sub nodes?

I need a php solution and I tried something like that:

```
foreach($xml->Shipment->Package->children() as $activites) { 
    echo $activites->Status->StatusType->Description;
}
```

But this doesn't work.
Any ideas?
Thank you :)

Comment: Did you try without `children()`?

Comment: that makes no sense oO - but I tried it anyway -> does not work :(

Comment: How does it not make sense? https://3v4l.org/BJDZC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `children()`, instead just iterate over the `Activities`.

For example:

```
<?php
$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TrackResponse>
    <Shipment>
        <Package>
            <Activity>
                <Status>
                    <StatusType>
                        <Description>Foo</Description>
                    </StatusType>
                </Status>
            </Activity>
            <Activity>
                <Status>
                    <StatusType>
                        <Description>Bar</Description>
                    </StatusType>
                </Status>
            </Activity>
            <Activity>
                <Status>
                    <StatusType>
                        <Description>Baz</Description>
                    </StatusType>
                </Status>
            </Activity>
        </Package>
    </Shipment>
</TrackResponse>';

$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);

foreach ($xml->Shipment->Package->Activity as $activites) {
    echo $activites->Status->StatusType->Description.PHP_EOL;
}
```

https://3v4l.org/BJDZC

Comment: Thats it ! Thanks a lot :)